# Nominatim is undefined when I use leaflet-routing-machine with angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, angular7

***Hello !***

I use *Leafletjs* library with Angular 7 (typeScript) for the first time,
for leaflet routing machine, I use this block of code, I have this error have you any idea ? :

component.ts :
  [image]

```
L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [L.latLng(48.8534, 2.3488), L.latLng(44.837789, -0.57918),],
      routeWhileDragging: true,
      show: true,
      language: 'fr',
      geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
      autoRoute: true
    }).addTo(this.mapInstance);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because you either have not imported the library or you have imported it but it loads after the map initialization.

Import like this:

```
import "leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css";
import "leaflet-routing-machine";
```

and then when the component has loaded:

```
ngOnInit() {    
    this.map = L.map("map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(this.map);

    L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [L.latLng(57.74, 11.94), L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)],
      routeWhileDragging: true
    }).addTo(this.map);
  }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-embed-leaflet-routing-machine-in-an-angular-app-dvepx)

Note that because of an API limitation you should test it in a incognito browser mode sometimes to get the route.